# Replacing large hashset with new values from DB

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection, hashset

I have a spring application, java 8, on startup I connect to DB to retrieve about 2 million records and I put them inside a HashSet of a specific bean and hold them in memory for various purposes.

Once every day I need to refresh this set. So simply I again connect to DB, retrieve result set, I say:

```
Set results = new HashSet();
for (Object object : resultSet) {
   results.add(object);
}
inMemoryHashSet = results;
```

Right at the end of this refresh, I have old **inMemoryHashSet** with 2 million elements, and I have **results** set with 2 million elements, and then I switch reference by saying **inMemoryHashSet = results;**
After that I guess garbage collector kicks in and removes old 2 million elements from memory.
Is there a way to optimize this so that I don't have 2 complete hashsets in memory at the same time?
Maybe calling garbage collector before I start again loading new 2 million elements from DB, but I know that GC cannot be forced, just suggested that it should be run?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. It doesn’t matter when the garbage collector will run. Your problem is that `inMemoryHashSet` is still reachable while the loop is constructing a new set and still containing 2 million elements. This is an issue of your application logic. Can you a) call `inMemoryHashSet.clear();` or b) do `inMemoryHashSet = Collections.emptySet();` before the loop? Or will it cause problems to have an empty set during the update? In other word, do other threads access `inMemoryHashSet` while the update is running?

Comment: @Holger thx for comment, since refresh of inMemoryHashSet is being done during night, not during working hours we could maybe call clear() or emptySet()
But how exactly those methods work regarding objects that are in memory. Are they immediatly destroyed, or GC comes to clean them at some point after?

Comment: The garbage collector will come whenever it thinks it is the right time, usually depending on the allocated and available memory and the actual memory needs. So, clearing does not free memory, but ensures that *if* there is a need for garbage collection at this point or a later point, it *can* reclaim the memory. Of course, if there is not enough heap memory to hold two sets with 2 million elements each in memory, the garbage collector will run at some point during the loop. Which will succeed if you did the necessary step at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @Holger . I will implement and test how it works.